# transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 value) throws up error with status 0

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

I wanted to transfer funds between two accounts in Ethereum(Rinkeby TestNetwork) so as per ERC Token implemention I used transferFrom() function and called it.But got this following error in truffle console

```
 Error: Transaction: 0xad9c1f2e748f026497b2ea89857076ee4837239dbae8aeedafae665711beeac4 exited with an error (status 0).

    Please check that the transaction:

        - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.

        - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.
 at StatusError.ExtendableError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-error/index.js:10:1)
    at new StatusError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/statuserror.js:29:1)
    at Object.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:181:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/method.js:142:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:439:23)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
```

Here is the initial code I used.

```
*/
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}
```

In the truffle console, I called the contract like this

```
MyAdvancedToken.deployed().then(t => token = t)
```

where MyAdvancedToken is the contract name.
Since token is the object for the contract I used transferFrom() like this.

```
token.transferFrom(web3.eth.accounts[0],web3.eth.accounts[1],60)
```

Comment: please verify your smart contract code in Rinkeby so we can give help

Comment: Make sure you have provided the allowance

Comment: The allowance map must have an allowance at least as high as the value to be transferred.

Comment: @Luiz Soares Here is my contract address in Rinkeby Test network-  0xa9a2fccbf77c0460e34acd14828a36104beb1fb2 and the contract was verified.

Comment: @Aniket please see the updated code same as ERC20 Token declaration.

Comment: @schemar please see the updated code same as ERC20 Token declaration.

Comment: @DivyaGalla can you show how you call the approve and transferFrom methods?

Comment: @schemar I'm using truffle console from there I'm calling only transferFrom() using this  token.transferfrom('0x580bdf21274a6ec6a5b59e84c6818f7dc4d93f9b','0xc126f05f394985CC5f513f004960949696d31a72',6000) where token is the object of the contract.

Comment: You must call approve first @DivyaGalla

Comment: How do you initialize Allowance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80369/discussion-between-divya-galla-and-schemar).

Comment: @DivyaGalla please post exactly the code that you use to call the methods. Then we can figure out where to put approve or how to fix it.

Comment: @slakov you call approve function with receiver address and the amount the user can take from the sender address. In this way, you are setting allowance for the receiver from the sender side.